# Defer JavaScript Load to Specific Page Anchor

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have some JavaScript code that I'd like to load only once the page scrolls to a certain id tag.

For example, imagine I have a script `model.js` and an html element
`<p id='anchor'></p>`.

My goal is to trigger the load of `<script src="model.js"></script>` at the point when the page reaches the `<p id='anchor'></p>`

I'm assuming there's a fairly trivial way to achieve this, but I'm having difficulty finding how how to do so. So far my research only yielded stuff using `defer` or `async` in the `<script>` load, but those don't seem to give me the results I want.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why do you not want the script to *load* until that point?  Why not load the script and simply not execute a particular operation until that point?

Comment: Would you like a solution in pure JS / jQuery?

Comment: @David that's a good point, I suppose it doesn't make a difference. The script uses D3 to do some heavy DOM manipulation, which also occurs from other scripts loaded at the beginning, so I'd like to push the other DOM stuff off until a certain point, so as not to slow down transitions, etc. To be fair, I *can* control the delays inside the script itself (I'm already doing event-triggers on scroll-locations), but I'd rather separate that logic, and figured delaying the entire script load is the cleanest way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to solve your problem, I decided to add the script to the DOM, once the scroll position of the element was reached and then set the `src` attribute to `model.js`.

In order to only add the script once, the first time the script was added, I removed the event listener from the `document`.

Using jQuery:

```
let anchorOffsetTop = $("#anchor").offset().top;

$(document).on("scroll", function () {
  console.log(anchorOffsetTop, $(window).height(), $(this).scrollTop());
  if ($(this).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > anchorOffsetTop) {

    let s = document.createElement("script");
    s.type = "text/javascript";
    s.src = "model.js";

    $("body").append(s); // add script to body
    $(document).off("scroll"); // remove event listener

    console.log(s);
  }
});
```

Using pure Vanilla JS:

```
let anchorOffsetTop2 = document.getElementById("anchor").offsetTop;

const addScript = () => {
  if (
    document.documentElement.scrollTop + window.innerHeight >
    anchorOffsetTop2
  ) {
    let s = document.createElement("script");
    s.type = "text/javascript";
    s.src = "model.js";

    document.body.appendChild(s);
    console.log(s);
    window.removeEventListener("scroll", addScript);
  }
};

window.addEventListener("scroll", addScript);
```

---

See [this](https://codepen.io/koder613/pen/BazbVXP?editors=1111) codepen to test the code out.

Comment: Thanks! I'm looking for a pure JS solution to reduce dependencies as much as possible, but this is great :)

Comment: @JaredWilber I have updated my answer with a pure JS solution too. Let me know if this is sufficient.

Comment: Hi! can it also lazy-load this way a third party api-s js? (in my case this one: https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.4.1/mapbox-gl.js) Do i need to listen to any additional (load)event to be able to use it? Just because it doesn't seem to work after i modified your snippet for this.) Thank you!

Comment: meanwhile i made it work by using 2 different anchor points.. reaching the second one gave enough time gap for having the api-s variables etc loaded. Not nice, but working until i figure out the proper listener in this case..